My code is losing state when I switch from one screen to another in flutter app
I have a flutter app where a new user is taken to the user profile screen. Here they can enter more information and save the data.
Just before the save method, I put all the data into a riverpod NotifierProvider and pass this data to the save method. This works well.
After the new user information has been saved, they are taken to a company profile screen where they can enter all the data about their company.
After the company has been saved, I retrieve the company document ID and I want to save it to the user record so they are linked.
However, sometime between the time the new user is saved and the company is saved, I lose all the data in the user NotifierProvider. I don't get any errors before I try to save the company ID in the user record.
Both screens extend ConsumerState, if that helps.
I have been able to narrow it down to the following code:
I am passing the user data to the save method
ref.read(usersNotifierProvider.notifier).
saveUser(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider), ref.read(usersNotifierProvider),);

This is the method:
saveUser(globals, user) async {
    if (ref.watch(globalsNotifierProvider).newUser == true) {
      // final DocumentSnapshot currentCompanyProfile =
      final newUser = Users(
        userId: user.userId,
        fName: user.fName,
        lName: user.lName,
        mls: user.mls,
        mlsId: user.mlsId,
        address1: user.address1,
        address2: user.address2,
        city: user.city,
        userState: user.userState,
        zipCode: user.zipCode,
        cellPhone: user.cellPhone,
        officePhone: user.officePhone,
        companyId: globals.companyId,
        companyName: user.companyName,
        email: user.email,
        businessType: user.businessType,
        deviceToken: user.deviceToken,
      );
      firestoreService.saveNewUser(toMap(newUser));
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false);
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentuserProfile =
          await userDB.doc(user.UserId).get();

      var newUser = Users(
          userId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUid,
          fName: (state.fName != null && state.fName != "")
              ? state.fName
              : currentuserProfile.get('fName'),
          lName: (state.lName != null && state.lName != "")
              ? state.lName
              : currentuserProfile.get('lName'),
          address1: (state.address1 != null && state.address1 != "")
              ? state.address1
              : currentuserProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: (state.address2 != null && state.address2 != "")
              ? state.address2
              : currentuserProfile.get('address2'),
          city: (state.city != null && state.city != "")
              ? state.city
              : currentuserProfile.get('city'),
          userState: (userState != null && userState != "")
              ? userState
              : currentuserProfile.get('state'),
          /*state: (globals.selectedState != null)
              ? globals.selectedState
              : globals.currentuserState,*/
          zipCode: (state.zipCode != null && state.zipCode != "")
              ? state.zipCode
              : currentuserProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: (state.cellPhone != null && state.cellPhone != "")
              ? state.cellPhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          officePhone: (state.officePhone != null && state.officePhone != "")
              ? state.officePhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('officePhone'),
          companyId: companyId,
          companyName: (state.companyName != null && state.companyName != "")
              ? state.companyName
              : currentuserProfile.get('Company'),
          mlsId: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).mlsId,
          mls: (state.mls != null && state.mls != "")
              ? state.mls
              : currentuserProfile.get('mls'),
          deviceToken: (state.deviceToken != null && state.deviceToken != "")
              ? state.deviceToken
              : currentuserProfile.get('deviceToken'));
      businessType:
      ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).userBusinessType;

      firestoreService.saveUser(
          newUser, ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentUserId!);
    }

This is where I do the actual save:
  Future<void> saveNewUser(users) {
    return _db.collection('users').add(users);
  }

When I come back from saving the data, the provider is empty.
Thanks

I removed this line and it worked:
  firestoreService.saveNewUser(toMap(newUser));
  ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewUser(false); <<<< REMOVED

